# combine 'git status' and find command with mmin or mtime option

Tags: linux, git, time, find, diff

'git status' command gives the list of files changed since the last commit.

find command with mmin or mtime option gives the list of files saved within a given time length. But it would also include files I have edited and then undone the changes i.e. those whose contents have not been changed.

What I need is to get the list of files which have been modified (contents changed) within a given time length. Is it possible ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

What you want is Git [`whatchanged`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-whatchanged).

Here's an example using `whatchanged` to show added files (I didn't happen to have modified files in the test repo I used, but you can easily limit the results to modified files instead of added files):

```
$ git whatchanged --after='2012-07-07 17:20' --before='2012-07-28 23:31' --diff-filter=A -r --oneline --name-only
82b9dcf F
E/F
95a02ce D
D
```

As is noted in the manual, `whatchanged` uses [`rev-list`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-list) and [`diff-tree`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff-tree) behind the scenes and `whatchanged` also uses options available with `rev-list` and `diff-tree`. The `diff-tree` `--diff-filter` option will:

> Select only files that are Added (A), Copied (C), Deleted (D), Modified (M), Renamed (R), have their type (i.e. regular file, symlink, submodule, ...) changed (T), are Unmerged (U), are Unknown (X), or have had their pairing Broken (B).

If you want to use `rev-list` and `diff-tree` directly (to avoid the commit log `whatchanged` wants to output), you could use:

```
$ git diff-tree --diff-filter=A -r --name-only $(git rev-list -n 1 --before='2012-07-07 17:20' HEAD) $(git rev-list -n 1 --before='2012-07-28 23:31' HEAD)
D
E/F
```

Comment: Thanks, it is a quite useful command. I had to use `--pretty=oneline` instead of `--oneline` to get it to work. But I think it gives all the files included in commits made in the given time range. It is including files which have been saved before the given time range.